# Is there an equivalent to ClippingStyle in Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, style

Say I show a sphere, but restrict the `PlotRange`.

`Graphics3D[Sphere[], PlotRange -> {-0.6, 1}]`

There's a hole there, that I'd like to plug up. In `Plot3D`, you could specify a `ClippingStyle` that would do this, but there is no similar option in `Graphics3D`.

I tried `ClipPlanes` and `ClipPlanesStyle`, but this styles the whole plane, not just the hole in the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to now, `Graphics3D` does not support cliping and filling.

- `RegionPlot3D`

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -.6, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, -.8}]
```

[image]

- `CSGRegion`

```
CSGRegion["Intersection", {Ball[], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -.6}, {1, 1, 1}]}, 
 BaseStyle -> Cyan, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, -.8}]
```

[image]